# Using radio for musical collaboration

Tags: united-states, legal, transceiver, transmission, music

I'd like to collaborate (e.g. play together) with other musicians in my local area and/or beyond.

Coronavirus has made in-person collaboration difficult.  Latency makes internet-based collaboration difficult.

Is there a legal way for a group of musicians to play together using radio in the united states?

Comment: Hello Andy, and welcome to this site. Since this site is about amateur radio, I assume you are asking if you can transmit music anywhere on ham radio. As the answer says, the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks @MikeWaters , even for one-to-one collaboration?  All examples I can find talk about broadcasting music so that many end points can listen to one source.  Is it true that two people are allowed to talk together, but if they start singing together, then then communication becomes illegal?